# Cannot export mysql data on workbench from azure (PROCESS privilege(s) ERROR)

Tags: mysql, azure, workbench

i am currently on workbench 8.0.22 and I have a database on azure, to which I am connected. Since a week, when I try to export my data locally, using the UI of workbench, I receive this error:

`mysqldump: Error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces`

I have tried the following, to solve this:

- disable add-locks and lock-tables in the export setting
- create dump in single transaction
- export data from the azure website directly (there is no export option displayed for me in the overview of the DB)

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you're connected to the database with a user account that does not have access to export the data. If a database administrator is not available to help you, I would suggest looking into solution #2 [here](https://anothercoffee.net/how-to-fix-the-mysqldump-access-denied-process-privilege-error/) -- but only if you're comfortable with running the export from the command line.  If you pursue Solution #1, make sure to heed the warnings about security issues.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the quick answer. I am listed on azure as the owner, but on workbench no users appear in the User and Privileges Panel. 
I could run it from the command line, then I will have to connect in the command line to the azure servers first and then run the command?

Comment: Yes, if you have access to the server that's hosting the database.  Which mysql service are you using in Azure?  Is It "Azure Database for MySQL servers"?  In that case, you won't have access to the OS.

Comment: If you don't have access to the OS, you could try running the export as the administrative user that was specified when creating the mysql Azure resource. (This should be viewable on the mysql resource in the Azure portal).  Be careful when connecting as a highly-privileged user to avoid doing damage.

Comment: It is indeed: Azure Database for MySQL servers. Thanks to your message I have checked and I see, as an owner I likely don't have the same rights as the admin. I will request now more rights from the admin and see if this will solve the issue. Thank you so much for the explanation!